# GWT Popup Panel Style CSS

Tags: gwt, popuppanel

I am trying to add Loading icon .gif within GWT popuppanel , but my Loading icon view is some what hard to see , Can  i get any CSS style to appear icon within the popuppanel to get rich look ?

Comment: animated ? use a gif... https://www.google.be/search?q=spinner&rlz=1C1GPCK_enBE387&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NN-FUsm_EYSu7Ab25YHADQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1086&bih=730#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=spinner+gif&tbm=isch

Comment: Yes, I am using .gif file for loading icon, but my popup panel Style is hard to see not having rich look